# Unknown: Multipart body parts limit exceeded -{value}. To increase the limit change max_multipart_body_parts in php.ini

Tags: php, multipart

While using Filepond in a Laravel-Filamentphp application, after selecting a file for upload the following message is returned in the request:

```
Multipart body parts limit exceeded -727379948. To increase the limit change max_multipart_body_parts in php.ini.
```

This seems to be php related, and not application related.

I am using php 8.1.23

I have tried to change the max_multipart_body_parts value in php.ini to various values, but nothing works.

I couldn't find much info about this online. Anybody encountered and solved this issue yet?

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the parameter then set the value to 1500

Comment: It worked for me